# constraints inlist for integer

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints

I need to write a constraint for credit card expiry year in the constraints

This is my constraints

```
static constraints = {
    cardNumber(nullable:false, blank:false, creditCard:true)
    expiryMonth(nullable:false, range:1..12)
    expiryYear(nullable:false, range:(defaultExpiryYear)..(defaultExpiryYear + YEARS_TO_LIST))
}
```

where `defaultExpiryYear = Current Year - 2000`
and `YEARS_TO_LIST = 10 years`.

But this case will fail if the year is `2095` because the range will go `expiryYear(nullable:false, range:95..105)`
but as the `expiryYear` is only 2 digit for the year `2105` it will give `05` and it will fail.

How do I convert it into get in inlist for the range?

Comment: Can you capture expiryYear as a full year vs just last 2 digits? It would be much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but from my point of view, you should not worry about things that are about 90 years in the future. in 90 years - who could guarantee that there are still credit cards? if there are still credit cards, will they have an "expiry year"? if they'll have an expiry date, how is it calculated?

so, sorry that this may not be the answer you expected, but given the speed of development of the past few years I would not worry about your problem in any way ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fix it please comment if you have any other good ideas
where epiryStartYear and expiryEndYear are 4 digits year
    expiryYear(nullable:false, InList:( getExpiryRangeList()))

```
def static private getExpiryRangeList() {
def  yearList = []
(expiryStartYear..expiryEndYear).each {
    yearList << it % 100
}
yearList
}
```

OR i can do

```
def static private getExpiryRangeList() {
[expiryStartYear..expiryEndYear].collect(it % 100)
}
```